# How to show the n-th order differentiable functions are linearly independent on an interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:** Let $f$ be an n-times differentiable function on an interval $I=(a,b)$. Show that if at a point $t_0 \in I$, $f(t_0)=f'(t_0)=...=f^{(n-1)}(t_0)=0$ but $f^{(n)}(t_0)=1$, then $f, f', ..., f^{(n)}$ are linearly independent on the interval $I$.

I tried to form an n-th order linear differential equation from f, and I also tried to connect this problem to Wronskian. But I cannot convince myself in both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose
$$
c_0f + c_2f' + \cdots + c_nf^{(n)} = 0
$$
on $(a, b)$. Evaluating the linear combination at $t_0$ shows $c_n = 0$. Now we have
$$
c_0f + c_2f' + \cdots + c_{n-1}f^{(n-1)} = 0. 
$$
Take the derivative to obtain
$$
c_0f' + c_1f'' + \cdots + c_{n-1}f^{(n)} = 0,
$$
then evaluate at $t_0$ to get $c_{n-1} = 0$. This process can evidently be continued inductively to deduce that $c_k = 0$ for all $0\le k \le n
$. Hence the derivatives are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you, that's helped a lot.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help. Please accept the answer if you like it.

Comment: When we take derivative for the second equation, should the ci's change?

Comment: No, they stay the same.

Comment: could you please explain that?

Comment: Taking the derivative of the linear combination, we have for each summand $(c_kf^{(k)})' = c_kf^{(k+1)}$. If you take the derivative of the resulting  linear combination, you get for each term $(c_kf^{(k+1)})' = c_kf^{(k+2)}$ and so on